# React Native IOS Issue: Xcode 12.2 / React Native 0.65 Build Fails, Any One Help Me to Build the IOS Version

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios, xcode12

ld: 7 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

**MY POD FILE**

require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/cocoapods.rb'enter image description here
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'dhenusya' do
use_unimodules!
config = use_native_modules!

use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

pod 'react-native-safe-area-context', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context'

pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'

pod 'react-native-geolocation', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/geolocation'

pod 'react-native-simple-toast', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-simple-toast'

pod 'RNGoogleSignin', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-google-signin/google-signin'

pod 'JWT', '3.0.0-beta.12'

end